# Cordova / Kendo development and debug workflow

Tags: html, cordova, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am going to develop an Android app using Cordova / Kendo. I am new to this kind of HTML5 app development, and given that I have the tools below already

- PhpStorm
- GenyMotion

My initial thoughts is

- I develop like a tradition web apps (using Phpstorm / Chrome web developer tool)
- when almost completed, deploy to GenyMotion emulator to test.
- If I need to do remote debugging on Chrome (Android), I can use the Chrome on Android 4.4 .
- I can use QUnit for unit testing

Am I right? Are there any missing pieces?

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to invest in using https://www.jshybugger.com/#!/ this allows you to debug android in versions lower than 4.4, which is a life saver.